# How to beautify '+' sign

Tags: symbols, characters

I am writing a document with LaTeX covering the basics of programming with C++ and unfortunately the '+' signs look kind of ugly to me: They seem to be too big, too thin (regarding the rest of the text) and also shifted downwards.

Here is a screenshot from my document (which is written in German):

[image]

The issue with the thickness is not visible here, because one has to zoom out to notice. The example is from a `\section{}`.

Are there any ways to do better? I haven't found a special '+' LaTex command, so I assume one has implement one's own solution.